# flutter - gradient backgroud color web application PB

Tags: flutter-web

i use a gradient background color for my project in flutter it look great in mobile platform but is not good in web browser

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIlqH.png)

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      gradient: LinearGradient(
        begin: Alignment.topCenter,
        end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        stops: [0.1, 0.35, 0.65, 0.9],
        colors: PuzzleColors.backgroundColors,
      ),
    ));
```

// PuzzleColors.backgroundColors is list of colors

Comment: Can you include your code instead of code-image.

Comment: thanks i include my code